# alignment problem

Tags: amsmath, align

I have the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
f_X(x)&=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \exp ( -x^2/2 )   &\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \\
g(x)&=(x^2-1)/2   &\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \\
\intertext{ so}
g'(x) &= x\\
g^{-1}(y)&= \pm \sqrt{2y+1}\\
\intertext{ Then}
f_Y(y) &= \frac{f_X(g^{-1}(y))}{g'(g^{-1}(y))}\\
&=  \frac{1}{|\pm \sqrt{2y+1}|}   \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp \left( -y-\nicefrac{1}{2} \right)\\
\intertext{where the support for $f_Y$ is $ y \in [(0-1)/2, \infty) = [-\nicefrac{1}{2} , \infty)$}
&= \frac{2}{\sqrt{2y+1}\sqrt{2 \pi}}  \exp \left( -y-\nicefrac{1}{2} \right)  &\forall y \in  [-\nicefrac{1}{2} , \infty) 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that I would like all the `\forall` to be aligned, but only the top 2 are, and the one on the bottom line is positioned to the left of the 2 at the top. I was under the impression that using `&` would cause the relevant items immediately following to be aligned, which is working fine for the `=` but not the `\forall`s.

Comment: The rule for the `align` environments is: `rlrlrl…`. You need an additional `&` in front of `\forall`.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `\nicefrac`? The result doesn't seem good at all.

Comment: @egreg thanks for your comment (much appreciated as I am a beginner in LaTeX). Do you think this is better $\left[-\frac{1}{2} , \infty \right)$ ?

Comment: @egreg Actually, it was the `\nicefrac` after the `exp` that seemed better to me. This didn't look good to me: ` \exp \left( -y-\frac{1}{2} \right)`

Comment: @longrob Definitely `$[-1/2,\infty)$` or, less preferably, `$[-\frac{1}{2},\infty)$`. I'd perhaps use `\frac{1}{2}` in the arguments to `\exp`. Your usages of `\left` and `\right` are not needed and should be avoided here and in these situations.

Comment: The `\nicefrac` in `\exp(-y-1/2)` is the one that makes the formula very ambiguous to the reader.

Comment: @egreg should I post a different question about fractions, as I foresee this exchange continuing? I appreciate your comments very much indeed, but I have questions about how to make my LaTeX better in this instance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need an additional `&` before the `\forall`s.

The reason for this is given in Qrrbrbirlbel's comment to the question, the alignment of an align are `rlrlrl...`, a right-aligned column followed by a left-aligned column, right, left etc. Hence, with just one `&`, the `\forall`s end up in a right-aligned column, while you want them left-aligned.

See also section **3.6 Equation groups with mutual alignment** in the [`amsmath` manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/amsmath).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicefrac,amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
f_X(x)&=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \exp ( -x^2/2 )  & &\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \\
g(x)&=(x^2-1)/2   & &\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \\
\intertext{ so}
g'(x) &= x\\
g^{-1}(y)&= \pm \sqrt{2y+1}\\
\intertext{ Then}
f_Y(y) &= \frac{f_X(g^{-1}(y))}{g'(g^{-1}(y))}\\
&=  \frac{1}{|\pm \sqrt{2y+1}|}   \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp \left( -y-\nicefrac{1}{2} \right)\\
\intertext{where the support for $f_Y$ is $ y \in [(0-1)/2, \infty) = [-\nicefrac{1}{2} , \infty)$}
&= \frac{2}{\sqrt{2y+1}\sqrt{2 \pi}}  \exp \left( -y-\nicefrac{1}{2} \right) & &\forall y \in  [-\nicefrac{1}{2} , \infty) 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant ! +1 thanks so much for the explanation.